# Unity ScrollView with multiline string Content height adaption

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

So, I have a growing string with many "\n". Every app start I will load the total string and every app use some new lines will be added.

The string is inside the Content of a ScrollView. But the Content size is not scaling with the string length. I want the Content to be exactly as high as the text lines go and be scrollable.

I can think of calculating the line count and set the content height manually. But maybe there is a more simple way? Please tell me your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a convenient non-code answer myself. You put the Text-Component directly on your Content GameObject. Then you use a ContentSizeFitter and set Vertical: Preferred. Also the Content anchors have to be set for variable height.

This enables me to dynamically set and scroll through a different text length with a ScrollView. (The font size is kept, to still fit the rest of the GUI)

I am still open for other answers.